# Pattern to insert multiple phone number in database

Tags: html

Here, I want to insert multiple phone number in database.
I have used like this,

```
<input type="text" multiple pattern="/^(?:\s*\d{8}\s*(?:,|$))+$/" name="contact_num_of_issue_raiser" class="form-control">
```

and

```
<input type="text" multiple pattern="^\+\d{8,11}(,\+\d{8,11})*$" name="contact_num_of_issue_raiser" class="form-control">
```

But both are not working what else multiple phone number is not inserting into the database.
Any suggestion?

Comment: so what exactly is the problem? the pattern isn't allowing multiple numbers, or your server-side DB code isn't working? those are two entirely different things.

Comment: pattern allowing multiple numbers but server side db code isn't working.

Comment: then why bother showing what's working? if you have server-side problems, then perhaps showing the server-side code would be called for?